# Should I add another gable vent to my attic?

Tags: insulation, roof, vent

I have a long house with a 3 sq foot gable vent on the east end.  I have two 6 ft long roof vents in the middle and I want to know if I should install another gable vent at the west end to increase airflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider airflow paths. Adding random vents is not always a good idea, as it can reduce flow from other parts of the system. Adding gable vents to a soffit/ridge vent system will likely reduce flow from the edges of the space.

If you have good soffit ventilation, do not add more gable vents. Instead, add ridge venting. If the soffits are solid, gable vents could be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at info in the net, you would need 240 square inches of vent to 1000 square feet of roof.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reasonably add it, add it. You can't have too much attic ventilation, but it's easy to not have enough.

Comment: "You can't have too much attic ventilation". That's not quite true. Gable vents and ridge vents don't mix well, as the ridge vent will pull from the gable vent, rather than through the soffits.